# Undeclared identifier, when defining macro to load vulkan function pointers

Tags: c++, vulkan

I am trying to get vulkan up and running with cmake. I am currently trying to dynamically load
the vulkan function pointers using this [example](https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/articles/api-without-secrets-introduction-to-vulkan-part-1.html)

Here they use a construct of macro's to make it easier to load all the function pointers from the vulkan loader.

Now I run into some issues when loading the pointers in that particular way, I get 3 errors that probably are closely related:

```
error C2065: 'vkGetInstanceProcAddr': undeclared identifier
error C2065: 'PFN_vkGetInstanceProcAddr': undeclared identifier
error C2146: syntax error: missing ';' before identifier 'GetProcAddress'
```

All thrown at list_vulkan_functions.inl(5,1)

I find it strange that within the example they don't include any files in the list_vulkan_functions.inl so it seems logical to me it throws the error of 'undeclared identifier', how could this ever work? I have seen multiple examples of this method so I must be doing something wrong but I can't seem to figure out what.

**list_vulkan_functions.inl**

```cpp
#ifndef EXPORTED_VULKAN_FUNCTION
#define EXPORTED_VULKAN_FUNCTION( function )
#endif

EXPORTED_VULKAN_FUNCTION( vkGetInstanceProcAddr ) // <--error gets thrown here

#undef EXPORTED_VULKAN_FUNCTION
```

This file then gets included in the following files:
**vulkan_functions.h**

```cpp
#ifndef VULKAN_FUNCTIONS_H_
#define VULKAN_FUNCTIONS_H_

#include "vulkan.h"

namespace vulkan_test
{
#define EXPORTED_VULKAN_FUNCTION(name) extern PFN_##name name;
#define GLOBAL_LEVEL_VULKAN_FUNCTION(name) extern PFN_##name name;
#define INSTANCE_LEVEL_VULKAN_FUNCTION(name) extern PFN_##name name;
#define INSTANCE_LEVEL_VULKAN_FUNCTION_FROM_EXTENSION(name, extension) extern PFN_##name name;
#define DEVICE_LEVEL_VULKAN_FUNCTION(name) extern PFN_##name name;
#define DEVICE_LEVEL_VULKAN_FUNCTION_FROM_EXTENSION(name, extension) extern PFN_##name name;

#include "list_vulkan_functions.inl"

} // namespace vulkan_test

#endif
```

**vulkan_functions.cpp**

```cpp
#include "vulkan_functions.h"

namespace vulkan_test
{
#define EXPORTED_VULKAN_FUNCTION(name) PFN_##name name;
#define GLOBAL_LEVEL_VULKAN_FUNCTION(name) PFN_##name name;
#define INSTANCE_LEVEL_VULKAN_FUNCTION(name) PFN_##name name;
#define INSTANCE_LEVEL_VULKAN_FUNCTION_FROM_EXTENSION(name, extension) PFN_##name name;
#define DEVICE_LEVEL_VULKAN_FUNCTION(name) PFN_##name name;
#define DEVICE_LEVEL_VULKAN_FUNCTION_FROM_EXTENSION(name, extension) PFN_##name name;

#include "list_vulkan_functions.inl"
} // namespace vulkan_test
```

And **vulkan_library.cpp**

```cpp
bool vulkan_test::load_vulkan_function(LIBRARY_TYPE const& vulkanLibrary)
{
#define EXPORTED_VULKAN_FUNCTION(name)                                                     \
    name = (PFN_##name)LOAD_FUNCTION(vulkanLibrary, #name);                                \
    if (name == nullptr)                                                                   \
    {                                                                                      \
        std::cout << "Could not load exported Vulkan function named: " #name << "\n";      \
        return false;                                                                      \
    }                                                                                      
                                                                                           
#include "list_vulkan_functions.inl"

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your `load_vulkan_function` function is declared inside the `vulkan_test` namespace and the `vulkan_functions.h` is included in `vulkan_library.cpp`.

The key here is that you have to assign the result of `LOAD_FUNCTION` to the `extern` variable `name` (which is basically `vulkan_test::vkGetInstanceProcAddr`) declared in `vulkan_test` namespace (see `vulkan_functions.h#8` - or [Intel's sources](https://github.com/GameTechDev/IntroductionToVulkan/blob/master/Project/Common/VulkanFunctions.h#L24)):

**vulkan_library.cpp**

```
#include "vulkan_functions.h"
...
bool vulkan_test::load_vulkan_function(LIBRARY_TYPE const& vulkanLibrary)
{
#define EXPORTED_VULKAN_FUNCTION(name)                                                   \
    vulkan_test::name = (PFN_##name)LOAD_FUNCTION(vulkanLibrary, #name);                 \
    if (vulkan_test::name == nullptr)                                                    \
    ...
```